# azure blob storage cli list directories

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I'm writing a PowerShell script that uses the Azure Storage CLI. I'm looking for a way to list only the directories under a certain path. I can easily list blobs using `az storage blob list` but I'm hoping I can just get the directories without post-processing the result. Given that Azure blob storage has a flat file structure, I'm not really sure this is possible but thought someone might know something I don't.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you're looking at certain path inside the same container ?

Comment: there is no directory inside a blob container, path are virtual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, Azure Blob Storage is flat. For a hierarchical filesystem, check out Azure File Storage.

Check out the quickstart for the CLI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-cli

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`--delimiter`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/79) option to get closer to what you want -- top level folders (and blobs), but not nested blobs:

```
# suppress nested blobs
$ az storage blob list -c foo --delimiter '/' --output table 

Name       Blob Type    Content Type             
---------  -----------  ------------------------- 
dir1/
dir2/
dir3/
dir4/
file.txt   BlockBlob    text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

This suppresses all the blobs at deeper levels. From there, you can filter down to just the "folders" because the folder entries have *zero* metadata, while the blobs do. The folder entries also end in a `/`. The `az` CLI can filter that for you, too, if you provide the query option:

```
az storage blob list -c foo --delimiter '/' --query '[].name | [?ends_with(@, `/`)]'

[ "dir1/",
  "dir2/",
  "dir3/",
  "dir4/" ]
```

Edit:

Another flag `--auth-mode login` might be needed if you have trouble with fetching resources due to the authentication issues

```bash
z storage blob list -c foo --auth-mode login --delimiter '/' --query '[].name | [?ends_with(@, `/`)]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deciding that this wasn't really an option since the file system is flat and the "paths" are just virtual. I decided to go a different direction with my script that didn't require batching based on these virtual directories.